# AdWords parallel tracking - what does it mean for me?

Tags: google-ads, click-tracking, google-ads-valuetrack

I'm using Google Ads (aka. Google AdWords) to market my website and Android application in Google search results. Today I received an email that says

> Starting October 30, 2018, parallel tracking will be required for all AdWords accounts, to ensure a better landing page experience for your users. At that time, the account opt-in setting will be removed and parallel tracking will become the only click measurement method for AdWords.
>
> **Next steps**
>
> Please work with your click measurement provider(s) to make sure that your account is ready for parallel tracking by October 30, 2018.

I went to the AdWords help website to read more about parallel tracking, but it basically just says the same things as the email.

**What is a click measurement provider, and does this concern simple AdWords users like me?**

I'm simply using the AdWords website to see statistics for my ads, as well as using Google Analytics to track normal (non adwords -related) stuff on my website, a setup I suspect most small websites use. I also have Adsense on my website if that matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel Tracking is an alternative to traditional click tracking offered by Google, which speeds page load time by running third-party trackers in the background instead of redirecting the user.

Generally users add [tracking parameters](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6325879?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en) for URLs in the AdWords to track it. But these URLs undergo Click measurement redirect.

**Click Measurement** - When you use a click measurement redirect (either your own or one from a third-party technology provider), the person who clicks on our ad first needs to be bounced through one or more redirect servers before their browser is able to even request the ad’s landing page.
Depending on how this is done, and how many redirects are used, this can add seconds to the user’s experience.

It affects the Page Load time which will directly affect the Quality Score of the Keywords.So [Parallel Tracking](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7544674?hl=en) needs to be used.

With parallel tracking, customers are delivered directly to your landing page while click measurement happens in the background.

No need to worry about it if you are not using the tracking parameters for URLs.Else need to make the changes as suggested by Google.